# Css grid grow to fit content

Tags: css, css-grid

I've been trying to wrap me head around css grid. Why doesn't the outer grid grow to the size of the inner grid in this example? How can I fix this layout?

```css
.scroll {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="grid">
      <p>Grid:</p>
      <div class="grid">
        <p>text here</p>
        <p>verylongtextherewithoutanybreakingoptions</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example you have two grids AND two other wrappers. Both grid are extended to the same size since they are made `inline-grid` but it's not the case of the `.wrapper` where you applied `box-shadow`.

Make the `.wrapper` `inline-block` and it will fix the layout.

```css
.scroll {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 1rem;
  display:inline-block;
}

.grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="grid">
      <p>Grid:</p>
      <div class="grid">
        <p>text here</p>
        <p>verylongtextherewithoutanybreakingoptions</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The outer `.grid` is always grow up with inner `.grid`. Which is fixed in here is width of `.scroll`